# presentViewController does not show Tab Bar or Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, presentviewcontroller

I am new to Swift and have been struggling with this for a while.

I am trying to redirect users based on login status to either "Login" viewcontroller or "Home" viewcontroller.

"Home" viewcontroller has NavigationBar and TabBar and it shows a table. But, when i use the following code, i see only the table. NavigationBar and TabBar are not shown at all.

```
var view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is my storyboard : https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkcz45n8000gua6/storyboard.png?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit (used TabBarController):

```
var view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabController") as UITabBarController
self.presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with being new to swift; it has to do with not understanding storyboards. If you instantiate HomeViewController, and present it, then that's all you will get. The fact that it's embedded in a tab bar controller and navigation controller in the storyboard is not "known" to this bare controller you just instantiated. You should instantiate the tab bar controller instead, and present it. It will take care of instantiating any of its children, and the navigation controller will take care of instantiating its root view controller.

Comment: I tried by providing UITabBarController Storyboard ID "MainTabController". But no luck :(. https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc2dyxd4ng327mh/tabbarcontroller.png?dl=0

Comment: @Puru, what does "no luck" mean? What result did it give you?

Comment: I see only the table without tabbar or navigationbar

Comment: @Puru, then did you instantiate the tab bar controller and present it? Edit you question to show the code you're using now.

Comment: i instantiated the "MainTabController" as UITabBarController. please see the update.

Comment: @Puru, that should have worked, so I'm at a loss as to why it didn't. There's got to be something not setup correctly somewhere, but I can't figure it out without actually seeing your project. If you can post it somewhere, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. At one of the places, i was instantiating UITabBarController as UIViewController. So, i was seeing the issue. Now, i have addressed it. Thanks for your help.